# Site loading speed very slow Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, performance, apache, slow-response

as per our architecture, we have a web server(Apache) running on one machine and my database(MySQL) running on different machine. The communication between these two machines in over internal network (without any firewall or any gateway).

We have a database heavy site with around 3000 products and the number is expected to grow. But the problem is that the site is taking too much of time to load (~30 sec). the waterfall diagram in browser shows that first response from server takes around 24-25 seconds and then the complete page loads in 30 seconds.

1. Images of the products are not heavy and also there is no need for CDN as the server location is in same geographical area.
2. the site is hosted on a private cloud
3. the score on GTMetrix is 96%

Any pointers to debug the issue will be much appreciated

Comment: First thing to check are caches, make sure they’re enable and are wirking (ie. They are saved and read from the storage).

Comment: We have checked cache have already enabled.Please suggest

Comment: please run profiler, to make sure magento code is ok.

Comment: if you have cache enabled and production mode `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` - make sure it works, reset php opcache. this will reload env.php settings

Comment: Thank you quick reply we have enabled cache as well as website in production mode but website speed are same.please help

Comment: Can you provide any more detail on technical spec on your servers? For example number of cores? How much memory? How much disk space? What version of php? Version apache? Version mysql?

Comment: Using the profiler as suggested will likely pinpoint areas for improvements. Another suggestion would be to sign up (even just temporarily) with a Magento specialised hosting company. Then run the same code and database there. If you are getting the same speed issues - you have confirmed the issue is with your code. If the speed is a lot faster the issue would be with your server set up.

Comment: @DominicXigen Can you provide any more detail on technical spec on your servers? For example number of cores 6  How much memory 16G How much disk space 100G What version of php 7.2  Version apache 2.4` Version mysql 5.7 –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points which you should have to keep always in mind such as:

a) Is file reading taking time : If you do not have SSD then some time can be lost.

b) Collect sql queries( As this can be one of the major cause ) that were fired with page cached. Its our experience that due to improper configuration or some non standard block code or due to some Modules the blocks are no cached but generated each time.
Here make sure that not more then  100 sql queries are getting fired.An uncached page might take almost a 1000 plus queries but a properly coded page will no 0 to 100 queries.

c) Some third party request was fired and code waiting for that response till the request times out.

Comment: We have found a solution regarding the Speed issue we have to disable reward point extension its load js every time